# Do Apple Geniuses check if computers are "lost" with iCloud's Find My Mac before performing firmware password resets?

Tags: apple-store, find-my-mac, firmware-password

Firmware password protection<sup>[1](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1352)</sup> is nice, but would the Genius Bar actually mind my "lost" status noted online if my computer ends up in a store to reset the firmware password (which is the easiest method to reset it)? Do they match the serial this way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I doubt it, and even if they did, you should not rely on it.

I assume you are concerned about the case where your laptop gets stolen; you want to protect your data. In that regard, the firmware password is utterly useless, the thief could just pull the drive out and access your data anyway.

I suggest you look into something like [FileVault 2](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4790) instead.

Comment: Changing the amount of RAM on the computer also resets the firmware password.